# C Dynamic List Troubles

Tags: c, list, dynamic

```
typedef struct {
    long blarg;
} item;

typedef struct 
{
    item* items;
    int size;
} list;
```

List and Item structs, fairly simple.

```
list l;
l.size = 3;
realloc(l.items, l.size*sizeof(item));
```

Create a list, allocate it to hold 3 items.

```
item thing;
item thing2;
item thing3;

thing.blarg = 1337;
thing2.blarg = 33;
thing3.blarg = 123;

l.items[0] = thing;
l.items[sizeof(item)+1] = thing2;
l.items[(sizeof(item)*2)+1] = thing3;
```

Create some items and add them to the list... but when printing them:

```
printf("List 0: %ld\n", l.items[0].blarg);
printf("List 1: %ld\n", l.items[sizeof(item)+1].blarg);
printf("List 2: %ld\n", l.items[(sizeof(item)*2)+1].blarg);

List 0: 1337 
List 1: 33 {
List 2: 1953720652 !
```

Where did it all go wrong?

Comment: Your `sizeof` operation is not correct when indecing the `items` member list. Suggest you read up on pointer arithmetic in C. The compiler will generate the correct byte-offset for you based on the underlying *type* of the pointer being indexed (its size) multiplied by the index offset request.

Comment: Don't you need to assign the value of the `realloc` call to the realloc'd thing?

Comment: Actually, don't you need to `malloc` some storage in the first place before trying to resize it?

Comment: @user2357112 The forgotten assignment actually did turn out to be my problem, but `realloc` functions like `malloc` on a NULL.

Comment: @SuperDisk correct. you can implement damn-near the entire C-memory lib using just `realloc()` (acts like `malloc()` when p is NULL, even acts like `free()` when size is 0). Its an entire memory mgmt lib all in one function.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be null, though. You never initialized it. realloc'ing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @user2357112 Good thing this thing I'm writing is only for one compiler and it works there.

Comment: Unless your compiler always zeros out uninitialized local variables, this is going to break again later. Most likely, the variable happened to be on a fresh region of stack this time, but that's an accident of allocation and control flow.

Comment: @user2357112 It's emscripten so I think it just creates a javascript array (which won't contain garbage, I don't think)

Comment: "This won't break on my compiler" is really not a good excuse to refuse to fix something that is, fundamentally, a bug. The C standard explicitly requires that the first argument to `realloc()` be either `NULL`, or a value previously returned from either `malloc()` or `realloc()`. Further, the C standard explicitly does not guarantee that an uninitialized pointer will have an initial value of `NULL`. (What C99 says, in fact, is _If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate._)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `l.items[sizeof(item)+1]` and `l.items[(sizeof(item)*2)+1]` --> `l.items[1]` and `l.items[2]`

Comment: With this, it outputs the first and second item correctly, but instead of even trying to print the third it just outputs "{".

Comment: @SuperDisk are you using indexes [0], [1] and [2] ***only*** (no sizeof or multiplications needed).

Comment: @SuperDisk Then check your output format flags, because the ones you show here don't even match the code you have here beside it, which already tells us you're not showing the *real* code (which you should *always* do, btw).

Comment: @WhozCraig According to the internet, %ld is the correct output flag (long integer?). Are you sure? I posted the real code and it looks the same to me. I did notice a typo however and updated my code and the post to fix.

Comment: @SuperDisk I understand `%ld` is the correct format spec. What i was referring to was the extraneous output *after*, and the carrot (`>`) *before*, neither of which are in your `printf()` format string. This the reason it appears the `printf()` statements you are showing did not generate the *output* listed immediately below. It is possible your stack is correct due to another error, but without more code (and context), it would be hard to say.

Comment: @whozcraig Oh, that, hoho. I tried to do a stackoverflow markdown >quote syntax, but it borked the formatting and I just turned it into code, forgetting to remove the carats. Sorry.

Comment: I only change `realloc(l.items, l.size*sizeof(item));` to `l.items = realloc(NULL, l.size*sizeof(item));` and it works fine in my computer. Beside realloc and index I don't see anything wrong with your sample code.

Comment: @SuperDisk [See it live here](http://ideone.com/49Zzw8) and compare it to what you're showing us. Note the output. It is correct in the linked sample.

Comment: @SuperDisk LOL. yeah, that would certainly do it. Maybe that was what Lidong meant when he said your realloc call makes no sense. (and I'm ashamed I didn't see it myself). If he undeletes his answer I'll up-vote it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
realloc(l.items, l.size*sizeof(item));
```

has just alloced l.size (namely 3) item elements,
while sizeof(item)+1 and  sizeof(item)*2+1 have exceeded the range of l.items array,
so the unknown value would be read, and in fact, segment fault should happen

If you want to use l.items in the way you did,
you should convert l.items to (void*) first, 
and then convert it back to item* while getting value of blarg